# Find periodic sequence formula for extrema of $x\sin(x)$, if possible

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions

How does multiplying $\sin(x)$ by $x$ shift the extrema points of the $\sin(x)$ function from periodic intervals of $\frac{n\pi}{2}$, where $n \in 2\mathbb{Z}+1$ (odd integers) to the offsets of

$x = 2.0287578,\ $
$x = 4.9131804,\ $
$x = 7.9786657,\ $
$x = 11.085538,\ $
$x = 14.207436,...\ $

and how does it change the regular sine functions $-1,1$ amplitude to the new amplitudes of $x\sin(x)$

Is it possible to create a formula to hits all these $x$ values (don't care how complex it may be, so long as it takes the integer n incrementally and returns one of those x values above), something that contains $\frac{n\pi}{2}$ and doesn't involve numerical approximations or using it's derivative at 0?

EDIT: In terms of numerical approximations, I would be happy with the limit approach such as using the example of $\tan(e^{x})$, where using the function $\ln(\arctan(999999999)\cdot n)$ as $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }$ or in this case 999999999 gets to a close approximation like using a sequence formula of $\ln(\frac{n\pi}{2})$.

note all you have to do it increment the value $n$, leaving $99999999$ alone

And if it's not possible, why so? What are the properties of the function $x\sin(x)$ that doesn't allow this to be so?

Comment: This equates to finding $x$ such that $$\tan{(x)}+x=0$$ which cannot be solved exactly as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extrema occur at the roots of

$$\sin(x)+x\cos(x)=0,$$ or $$\tan x=-x.$$

As the tangent has vertical asymptotes at $x=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$, the solutions are close to these values. More precisely, $x\approx\left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi$ in the positives.

Now using Taylor,

$$\tan x=\frac1{\tan\left(\left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi-x\right)}\approx\frac1{\left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi-x}$$

giving the quadratic equation

$$x^2-\left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi x-1=0$$ that you solve for $x$.

$$x=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{17}4}+2n+1}4$$

You can improve on this solution by means of one Newton's iteration,

$$x\leftarrow x-\frac{\tan x+x}{\tan^2x+2}.$$

The analytical expression in terms of $n$ is heavy:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{17}4}+2n+1}4-\frac{\tan \dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{17}4}+2n+1}4+\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{17}4}+2n+1}4}{\tan^2\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{17}4}+2n+1}4+2}.$$

The first root, corresponding to $n=0$ is $2.056952$, and the improved value $2.027446$. Then $\tan 2.027446=-2.0354865$.

The larger $n$, the better the approximations.

---

**Update:**

The last formulas are wrong as the factor $\pi$ was dropped. But the numerical values are correct.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but I don't seem to be getting the same values as you for n, whether with the heavy analytical expression or the expression that was solved from the quadratic equation. Am I doing something wrong?

heavy analytical expression n values
n = 0 -> .174860355616
n = 1 -> 1.14098459408
n = 10-> 7.95324717236

Comment: @C9C: ouch, the factor $\pi$ was dropped from the quadratic equation.

Comment: Of course, yes! The correct formula is $\frac{1}{4}\left(4n\pi\pm \sqrt{\left(4n\pi+\pi\right)^2+16}+\pi\right)$

Comment: @C9C: only $+$.

Comment: Hi Yves ! When you think about it, a $[1,2]$ Padé approximant is Householder first iteration. This why I enjoy them. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: hi Claude. Why not. Just need to evaluate the computational cost vs. accuracy.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was too embarrassed to ask you to elaborate, but I just can't figure out how you got the follow using Taylor series and how tan(x) = that fraction

$tan(x) = \frac{1}{tan((2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi - x)}\approx \frac{1}{(2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi - x}$

Yeah, it's been a year and I gave up at first, but it keeps bugging me every so often! I'd need the step-by-step process if it's not too much trouble

Comment: @C9C: $t:=(2n+\frac12)\pi-x$ is a tiny number so that $\tan t\approx t$ holds by Taylor.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So you didn't derive $(2n+\frac12)\pi-x$ from $tan(t)$ using taylor expansion, you just chose it because it gives the locations of the asymtotes which are close to $tan(x)=-x$.

Also, it doesn't seem like you're using quadratic approximation to get the quadratic equation. If so, what function are you using to get the derivatives for it?

Comment: @C9C: hem, $\dfrac1{\left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi-x}=-x$.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as in @Yves Daoust's answer, instead of Taylor series, we could build Padé approximants of $\sin(x)+x\cos(x)$ around $x=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$.

In order to keep it simple (that is to say one linear equation), let us use for example the $[1,2]$ Padé approximant. I skip the intermediate calculations but we end with the simple
$$x=t+\frac{6 t^2+9}{t(6 t^2+17)} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$$

Below are given the results for the first solutions
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0 & 2.047282372 & 2.028757838 \\
 1 & 4.913295940 & 4.913180442 \\
 2 & 7.978674318 & 7.978665712 \\
 3 & 11.08553997 & 11.08553841 \\
 4 & 14.20743717 & 14.20743673 \\
 5 & 17.33637808 & 17.33637792 \\
 6 & 20.46916747 & 20.46916740 \\
 7 & 23.60428481 & 23.60428477 \\
 8 & 26.74091603 & 26.74091601 \\
 9 & 29.87858652 & 29.87858651
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the $[1,3]$ Padé approximant, we should get
$$x=t+\frac{4 t \left(6 t^2+17\right)}{24 t^4+100 t^2+49} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$$ For the first root, this would give $2.02306$ (corresponding to a relative error of $0.28$%).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Padé approximants, but it look very interesting so I'll have a look into it sometime. Thanks for the suggestion and example

Comment: @C9C. It is much more than interesting, be sure ! Search here for "Padé"; something like 500 entries. Cheers.